# What wrong with Debian port open configuration?

Tags: tomcat, https, configuration, connection, debian

I use tomcat 9.0.3 with this configs:

```
<Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="mystore2" keystorePass="PWD"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

and this listners:
org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener 
org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener 
org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener 
org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener

when I try connect from browser it throw ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I try open 8443 port by:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
ufw allow https
```

But when I check remotely port closed
even though result of ufw status:

> Status: active
>   To                         Action      From
>   --                         ------      ----
>   OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
>   8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere
>   8443                       ALLOW       Anywhere
>   22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
>   80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
>   443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
>   OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
>   8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
>   8443 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
>   22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
>   80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
>   443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN:

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      622/sshd
>   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      684/mysqld
>   tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      622/sshd
>   tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      618/java
>   tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      618/java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in wrong configuration of . 
When I created password, I set it for key and for store.
After delete key password, all go well